# When can we use a monic morphism to copy an algebraic structure?

Tags: category-theory, monads

Let $(T,\mu, \eta)$ be a monad over the category $\textbf A$ , let $(A,a)$  be a $T$- algebra and $m: B\rightarrow A$ be monic. Prove a morphism $b:TB\rightarrow B$ is the structure for an algebra such that $m$ is a morphism of $T$-algebras if and only if the following diagram commutes:

[image]

I just don't know where to start. Of course I have to assume the diagram commutes and then see it is a morphism of $T$-algebras and vice-versa , but I get stuck on all the specifics.

Comment: Since $m$ is a monomorphism and $m\circ b\circ \mu_B=a\circ T(m )\circ \mu_B=a\circ \mu_A\circ T^2(m)= a\circ T(a) \circ T^2(m)=a\circ T(a\circ T(m))=a\circ T(m \circ b)=a \circ T(m) \circ T(b)=m\circ b\circ T(b)$ it follows that $b\circ \mu_B=b\circ T(b)$ etc...

Comment: Thanks, why do we have $a\circ T(m)\circ \mu_B=a \circ \mu_A \circ T^2(m)$?

Comment: Oh wait, that's the naturality of $\mu$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  Wouldn't the naturality be $\mu_B\circ T^2(m)= T(m) \circ \mu_A$ ?

Comment: Lol, nevermind. I accidentally thought $m$ went from $A$ to $B$. My bad.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to finish nicely with that!